# How to display an image from a string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have featured_image that i get from an axios call, the image is saved in the src folder, src/img. It's a string and it's equal to "../img/blog1.jpg".

I can't have the background image dispalyed i believe it needs to be converted to a static image somehow.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
const Post = ({ post: { title,
featured_image, category, slug, summary }, index }) => {

  return (  
    <div>
        <div role="listitem" className="post-v1 w-dyn-item">
            <div className="post-card-v1">
            <Link to={slug} className="post-v1-thumb w-inline-block">
                <div className="post-v1-image" style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + featured_image + ")"}}></div>
            </Link>
            <div className="post-v1-content">
                <div className="post-card-more-info">
                    <div className="badge post-v1-badge">{category}</div>
                </div>
                <Link to={slug} className="link-white w-inline-block hover-blog">
                    <h4 className="uppercase text-white">{title}</h4>
                </Link>
                <div className="text-white">{summary}</div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};
  
export default Post;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using static images in react app you better should move them to the `public` folder

**featured_image value example** `'img/1.jpg'`
assuming you moved the whole folder img to public

Why would i put them in public folder?
answer:

- If you put any kind of file into the public folder, it will not be
  processed by webpack. it will be copied into the build folder as it
  is.
- To give the access to all the components/pages to this file(html/img) with one same path no matter is deep the component in folders

Comment: Thanks, why would i do this? I have no issue of displaying images using the src folder since i do npm run build after.

Comment: I have updated  the answer for you question ,hope it's clear if not ask me

Comment: It works if i put them in public/img thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in the brackets, you write js, so you should use string interpolation :

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${featured_image})`}}
```

Comment: does not work the output is background-image: url("../img/blog1.jpg"); the image located in src/img do not show cheers